# Accessing Soundcloud waveform/artwork for WebGL (three.js) app - CORS issue

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, cors, soundcloud

I'm working on a WebGL app which uses data from the soundcloud API.

I'm trying to use ThreeJS to load the track artwork and waveform PNGs into textures to put onto sprites.

But I'm getting the error in chrome:

> Image from origin [soundcloudapi] has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

So I've been reading up on CORS and it seems from the Soundcloud documentation that CORS is supported in some way for the JSON data ([Soundcloud CORS](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#crossdomain)) but I'm not sure if or how this extends to requesting the pngs associated with tracks.

I've also read a little about Three.js and CORS and so I've included the line:

```
THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
```

I put this like before I call 'loadTexture()' anywhere but I'm still getting the same error.

I was thinking one workaround would be to request the PNG in javascript and then make an AJAX request to a php file while just grabs the image and temporarily stores it on my server but that's not really efficient if a lot of people end up using my app (and probably isn't legal or something from Soundcloud's point of view). So I want to avoid this as much as possible.

Has anyone tried this before? Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hmm this is interesting - it seems artwork_url does have the CORS headers because I can display them now in three.js after I set crossOrigin to 'anonymous' but waveform_url does not have the CORS headers. Any chance the Soundcloud team could add them?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a couple of months ago, I'm using http://www.waveformjs.org/ to get the waveform data.
It's made by somebody at Soundcloud. If you have some kind of backend you can check the repo (it's in ruby though), otherwise you can request the data pretty easily (when it's not down, like right now):

```
$.ajax(
    url: 'http://www.waveformjs.org/w'
  , dataType: 'jsonp'
  , data: url: waveform_url
)
```

From the data (an array of number from 0 to 1), you can reconstruct the waveform, that's what I'm doing using D3, [you can check how in this project](https://github.com/Calvein/soundcloud-playlist/blob/gh-pages/src/app/components/waveform/index.coffee)
It's not an ideal answer but at least it's working for me (again, when it's not down :/).